# How to Detect the ringback tone of an outgoing Calls in Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, tone-generator

I would like to know how to detect the ringback tone of an outgoing call, in order to compute the period between the detection of an outgoing call and the ringback tone.
Now, I can detect the outgoing call, but not the ringback tone.

Comment: Cell phones don't have dial-tones. Do you mean the ringing indicator?

Comment: Yes, I mean ringing indicator, Excuse me, I don't know exactly the technical terms.

Comment: Android doesn't report call progress back to your app, so the best guess would be to empirically determine how long it "usually" takes between dial and ringing, and then conclude that total ringing time is the time between that and the phone going off-hook.

Comment: If you're talking about the periodic audio indication that you hear during an outgoing call while you're waiting for the other party to pick up, it's called a _ringback tone_.

Comment: Please, we don't have idea???

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45223/how-to-detect-and-remove-dial-tone-and-ivrs-voice-etc-from-the-beginning-of-an-a 

Please help me with ^ question. 
I too am trying to detect the ringback tone.